# Mysql Query not summing mutliple records, just taking the first record only

Tags: php, mysql

We have a table (survey) which has different survey questions.  Each survey_id only appears once in this table.

We have a table of votes (vote_survey_table), which logs the user votes for each survey question.  The table has fields for survey_id, vote_yes, vote_no, user_id, etc. This table has more than one entry for each survey_id.

I'm trying to query the vote table to add up all the votes for a given survey question, but the query I'm coming up with only adds up the first instance of the row int he vote table.

```
SELECT survey.survey_id, vote_survey_table.vote_yes AS cnt,
survey.survey_name, survey.survey_details 
FROM survey 
LEFT JOIN vote_survey_table AS votedb ON vote_survey_table.vote_survey_id = survey.survey_id
GROUP BY survey.survey_id
ORDER BY cnt DESC, survey.survey_id LIMIT 0,5
```

What am I missing on this query that should tell the query to add up all the instances of a survey_id in the vote table and sum up the result?  I tried changing the LEFT JOIN to an INNER JOIN, but this didn't do the trick either.

Thanks in advance as always.

Comment: For one thing, you are not using `SUM` or `COUNT` anywhere. So how are you expecting the aggregation to occur?

Comment: grouping does not add up automatically. Use count(yes)

Comment: Are the field `vote_yes` and `vote_not` boolean fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sum the votes.

```
SELECT survey.survey_id, SUM(vote_survey_table.vote_yes) AS cnt,
       survey.survey_name, survey.survey_details 
FROM survey LEFT JOIN vote_survey_table AS votedb 
              ON vote_survey_table.vote_survey_id = survey.survey_id
GROUP BY survey.survey_id, survey.survey_name, survey.survey_details 
ORDER BY cnt DESC, survey.survey_id LIMIT 0,5
```

If `vote_yes` is a boolean field, then use `COUNT` instead of `SUM`.

Answer (score 1):

You are not summing up at all. You should use an aggregate function like

```
SELECT SUM(vote_survey_table.vote_yes) AS cnt
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: OP haven't told us if the field has a '1' or something that can't be added up. Other than that, I fully agree with this answer :)

Comment: I should've mentioned that, yes the field is an integer field with a count in it.  Thanks, the fix worked!